# unable to launch android sdk manager within eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk

my installation of eclipse+android happened successfully but for past few days im unable to launch android sdk manager within eclipse

so when i launch i get:

```
[2013-03-29 14:45:00 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager] 'D:/Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
[2013-03-29 14:45:00 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager] operable program or batch file.
[2013-03-29 14:45:00 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager] Invalid path
```

my eclipse version is:

Version: Indigo Service Release 2
Build id: 20120216-1857

os: windows 7 (32-bit)

i did checked my environment variable & it reads:

D:\Java\jdk1.7.0_13\bin;D:\Android\android-sdk\tools

and the AVD runs fine except with a warning:

```
[2013-03-29 14:46:09 - SDK Manager] Warning: Ignoring platform 'android-1.5': build.prop is missing.
```

(installed api 1.5, so that i can target apps for oses ranging from 1.5 to as 4.2.2 jelly bean)

Comment: did you ever find out what is wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

got it working by re-setting java path to appear before system32 path, in `environment variables`.

may be eclipse was searching for java at my previous location (at system32, which is now obsolete)

Comment: i dont understand your answer well enough to try it for myself, could you expain how you did this

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you have changed the location of the Android SDK to an invalid path. Try the following: `Window -> Preferences -> Android` and under `SDK Location` browse your folder containing the SDK and click `Apply`. Make sure that in the selected folder is a file named `SDK Manager`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but i got it fine by moving my eclipse folder from 'E drive' to 'C drive' and SDK manager is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that the error means that Android is looking for some folder, likely Java, under "D:\Program Files\". That is to say, you may have another Jre installed under "D:\Program Files\".